Defining empty element with attribute in XSD
I am following this tutorial where it is specified empty elements can be defined as

a complex type with a complex content. The complexContent element signals that we intend to restrict or extend the content model of a complex type, and the restriction of integer declares one attribute but does not introduce any element content.

However when testing it using Visual Studio with the XML plugin from RedHat I am getting the following error:

src-ct.1: Complex Type Definition Representation Error for type '#AnonType_product'. When  is used, the base type must be a complexType. 'integer' is a simpleType.

The code I am testing:
<xs:element name="product">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

Am I doing something wrong, the tutorial is out of date or it's the plugin which has an error?
EDIT: I know there is an alternative way, which is also specified in the tutorial, to define an empty element with an attribute, that actually works.
<xs:element name="product">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

My question is why the first method is not working.
